# Javascript focus not retaining

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where radio button options need to be selected. When there is any unselected option and someone submit it, it will show a pop up error message.

When press ok on pop up window it will close the pop up and come back to the parent window and set focus on unselected option(radio button). I used below methods to set the focus. After pressing ok button it goes to the unselected option but focus does not retain on it.

calling a function to close the popup window from parent window

```
<a alt="Ok" href="javascript:;" onclick="forceAndClose()" >OK</a>
```

function to close and set focus to the radio button element. Id 'missing' is set to unselected option

```
function forceAndClose(){
    dijit.byId('errorDialog').hide();
    var foc=document.getElementById("missing");
    foc.focus();
    foc.scrollIntoView();
    return;
}
```

It seems after clicking "ok" button it loads the parent html file again for which the focus removes from the element.

Help me to retain the focus on that unselected option.

thanks

Comment: pls post your radio buttons too

Comment: The code you posted works (assuming a radio with id "missing" exists) so you haven't included enough to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use return false instead of using simple return. As it will block the re-rendering of your page.

```
function forceAndClose(){
    dijit.byId('errorDialog').hide();
    var foc=document.getElementById("missing");
    foc.focus();
    foc.scrollIntoView();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried using false but the result is same. Is there any other way.

Comment: @BjRaj try <a alt="Ok" href="javascript:;" onclick="**return** forceAndClose()" >OK</a>